# Error al realizar borrado de Foreign Keys con LINQ + Entity Framework

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

en una aplicación sencilla de CRUD en donde tenemos un listado de videojuegos, he intantado borrar algunos de sus registros. La base de datos al contener Foreign Keys no me permite realizarlo sin antes eliminar todos los registros asociados a ese videojuego como por ejemplo, las puntuaciones o la plataforma a la que pertenece.

Lo he intendo mediante consultas linq de las siguientes formas:

```
var deleteFK = from JuegoPlataforma in context.JuegoPlataformas
                       where JuegoPlataforma.IdJuego == id
                       select (JuegoPlataforma.IdJuego);

        context.JuegoPlataformas.Remove(deleteFK);
```

---

```
context.JuegoPlataformas.Remove(context.JuegoPlataformas.Where(x => x.IdJuego == id));
```

Pero de las dos me reporta el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ajunto además el modelo JuegoPlataformas que además hace referencia a JuegoPlataformas, simplemente se ha modificado el nombre para una mayor legibilidad del código:

```
namespace Videojuegos_MartinN.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class JuegoPlataforma
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public JuegoPlataforma()
    {
        this.Puntuacion = new HashSet<Puntuacion>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdJuego { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdPlataforma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdDistribuidor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdDesarrollador { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdDesarrollador")]
    public virtual Desarrollador Desarrollador { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdDistribuidor")]
    public virtual Distribuidor Distribuidor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdJuego")]
    public virtual Juego Juego { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdPlataforma")]
    public virtual Plataforma Plataforma { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ICollection<Puntuacion> Puntuacion { get; set; }
}
```

}

Por ahora no se me ha ocurrido hacerlo de otras formas, ya que no puedo realizar un borrado en cascada.

En el proyecto, se hace uso además de Entity Framework.

Cualquier documentación o comentario sería de gran ayuda. Si se necesita alguna información adicional, la ofreceré lo antes posible. Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Hola, puedes indicar por favor los modelos JuegoPlataforma y JuegoPlataformas ?. por que veo que son dos modelos diferentes no?

Comment: Otra cosa, si utilizar Entity Framework, indícalo también en la pregunta por favor.

Comment: He añadido todos los cambios. Los modelos de JuegoPlataforma y JuegosPlataformas son el mismo. Le he añadido una 'S' al nombre original de la tabla en la base de datos para añadirle mejor legibilidad al código.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tu problema es que estas intentando borrar un conjunto de registros de una sola vez, y debes hacerlo de uno en uno.

El código sería así:

```
foreach (var _elemento in context.JuegoPlataformas.Where(x => x.IdJuego == id)) 
{
   context.JuegoPlataformas.Remove(_elemento);
}
context.SaveChanges();
```

También podrías eliminarlos de una sola vez (solo para EF 6.0 o superior) de la siguiente manera:

```
var _elementos = context.JuegoPlataformas.Where(x => x.IdJuego == id);
context.JuegoPlataformas.RemoveRange(_elementos);
context.SaveChanges();
```

Comment: Funciona pefecto, muchas gracias. Sólamente me qued con una duda, al querer borrar también la puntuaciones me vuelve a dar error por FK con la siguiente intrucción:                                                                                                                        var _elementos = context.Puntuaciones.Where(x => x.idjuegoplataforma == id);

Comment: Formula entonces otra pregunta, ya que cambian los Modelos y hay que ver por que es ese error.

Comment: Recuerda marcar el check verde al lado de la respuesta que te ha solucionado la pregunta, con eso estarás colaborando con la buena salud de este sitio. Gracias.

Comment: Muchas gracias, formularé una nueva pregunta en breve.

Comment: Le dejo el link del post por si le interesa revisarlo: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/298785/instrucci%c3%b3n-delete-en-conflicto-con-la-restricci%c3%b3n-reference-fk . Muchas gracias.