# Instrucción DELETE en conflicto con la restricción REFERENCE FK

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, linq

En una aplicación sencilla de CRUD en donde tenemos un listado de videojuegos, he intantado borrar algunos de sus registros. La base de datos al contener Foreign Keys no me permite realizarlo sin antes eliminar todos los registros asociados a ese videojuego como por ejemplo, las puntuaciones o la plataforma a la que pertenece.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

En el controlador de la aplicación tengo el siguiente código:

```
  public ActionResult Delete(int? id, bool? saveChangesError = false) {

        if (id == null)
            return new HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);

        if (saveChangesError.GetValueOrDefault()) 
            ViewBag.ErrorMessage = "Delete failed. Try again, and if the problem persists see your system administrator.";

        Juego game = context.Juegos.Find(id);

        if (game == null)
            return HttpNotFound();

        return View(game);
    }

    [HttpPost]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public ActionResult Delete(int id) {

        try {

        var platformFK = context.JuegoPlataformas.Where(x => x.IdJuego == id);
        context.JuegoPlataformas.RemoveRange(platformFK);

        var scoreFK = context.Puntuaciones.Where(x => x.idjuegoplataforma == id);
        context.Puntuaciones.RemoveRange(scoreFK);

        Juego game = context.Juegos.Find(id);
            context.Juegos.Remove(game);
            context.SaveChanges();
        }
        catch {
           return RedirectToAction("Delete",
                new { id = id, saveChangesError = true });
        }
        return RedirectToAction ("Index");
    }
```

Al método que Delete [httpost] le paso el ID del videojuego seleccionado. Para posteriormente borrar todos los registros asociados a él que tienen la restricción de Foreing Key.

El problema es que no me permite borrar las puntuaciones, adjunto el modelo de Puntuaciones a continuación:

```
    namespace Videojuegos_MartinN.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Puntuacion
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Idcliente { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> idjuegoplataforma { get; set; }
    [Column("Puntuacion")]
    public Nullable<int> Puntuacion1 { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> Fecha { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("id")]
    public virtual Cliente Cliente { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual JuegoPlataforma JuegoPlataforma { get; set; }
 }
}
```

Adjunto además los siguientes modelos de datos que se encuentran relacinados:

```
   namespace Videojuegos_MartinN.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class Cliente
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public Cliente()
    {
        this.Puntuacion = new HashSet<Puntuacion>();
    }
    [Key]
    public int id { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Nombre requerido")]
    public string Nombre { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "EMail requerido")]        
    [DataType(DataType.EmailAddress, ErrorMessage = "E-mail is not valid")]
    public string Email { get; set; }
    [DataType(DataType.Date, ErrorMessage = "Fecha nacimiento incorrecta")]
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaNacimiento { get; set; }
    public Nullable<System.DateTime> FechaRegistro { get; set; }

    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ICollection<Puntuacion> Puntuacion { get; set; }
}
}
```

---

```
namespace Videojuegos_MartinN.Models
{
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;
    using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.Schema;

public partial class JuegoPlataforma
{
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2214:DoNotCallOverridableMethodsInConstructors")]
    public JuegoPlataforma()
    {
        this.Puntuacion = new HashSet<Puntuacion>();
    }

    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdJuego { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdPlataforma { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdDistribuidor { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> IdDesarrollador { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdDesarrollador")]
    public virtual Desarrollador Desarrollador { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdDistribuidor")]
    public virtual Distribuidor Distribuidor { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdJuego")]
    public virtual Juego Juego { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("IdPlataforma")]
    public virtual Plataforma Plataforma { get; set; }
    [System.Diagnostics.CodeAnalysis.SuppressMessage("Microsoft.Usage", "CA2227:CollectionPropertiesShouldBeReadOnly")]
    [ForeignKey("Id")]
    public virtual ICollection<Puntuacion> Puntuacion { get; set; }
}
```

}

En la aplicación se usan tecnologías como Entity Framework y Linq.
Agradecería cualquier documentación u opinión. Muchas gracias.

Comment: Indica por favor el Modelo JuegoPlataforma.y Cliente, ya que son tablas relacionadas.

Comment: Revisa esto tal vez te sea útil https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/105890/que-significa-cascade-set-null-restrict-no-action-en-mysql/105921#105921

Comment: Han sido adjuntados los modelos correspondientes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para realizar "borrados en cascada" en EF, debes comenzar eliminando los registros de las Entidades más genéricas (tablas relacionadas) y finalizar por las entidades principales (tablas maestras).

En tu caso parece que lo estás haciendo bien, pero debes guardar los cambios en cada eliminación.

Primero elimina de la tabla Puntuaciones y guarda los cambios:

```
    var scoreFK = context.Puntuaciones.Where(x => x.idjuegoplataforma == id);
    context.Puntuaciones.RemoveRange(scoreFK);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Luego de la tabla JuegoPlataforma y guarda los cambios:

```
    var platformFK = context.JuegoPlataformas.Where(x => x.IdJuego == id);
    context.JuegoPlataformas.RemoveRange(platformFK);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

Y por último de la tabla principal donde se encuentra el registro original (Id):

```
    Juego game = context.Juegos.Find(id);
    context.Juegos.Remove(game);
    context.SaveChanges();
```

El proceso, sería tal y como te indico. Como seguro que tendrás más tablas relacionadas, y en el caso que te vuelvan a dar más errores de Foreing Key, prueba a cambiar el orden en el que eliminas los datos de las tablas en función de la lógica relacional de tu Base de Datos (Tu eres el que mejor la conoces).

Comment: El problema persiste, al realizar el segundo 'context.SaveChanges();' me un error como el mostrado en la foto de este post, algo raro ya que antes de eso ya había guardado cambios. ¿Puede ser un error relacionado con el modelo de datos, o quizás que no se está borrando de forma adecuada la Foreign Key que se encuentra en la tabla Puntuacion?

Comment: Observa la tabla Puntuación. Tiene una relación con la tabla Cliente, y esta a su vez tiene otra con Puntuación. Debes ir eliminando con la lógica adecuada. Revisa bien las relaciones de tu BD.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias por la rapidez con la que has respondido y la claridad, me pondré con ello, no cierro aún el post hasta que dé con el problema, seguiré escribiendo y postearé la solución final. Un saludo.

Comment: Si hiciese lo que dices y uno de los proceso falla quedan colgados los datos. Se tiene que hacer en un único SaveChanges()

Answer (score 0):

Primero necesitas representar en el DBConntext las relaciones del modelo de BBDD

```
 entity.HasOne(d => d.IdStudentNavigation)
                    .WithMany(p => p.Sports)
                    .HasForeignKey(d => d.IdStudent)
                    .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Cascade)
                    .HasConstraintName("FK_Sports_Students");
```

[Tutorial](https://docs.microsoft.com/es-es/ef/ef6/modeling/code-first/fluent/relationships?redirectedfrom=MSDN#RequiredToOptional)